# Unable to get HttpPost response from HttpClient POST

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am sending an Http Post request asynchronously.

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(HOST);

httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", hashval );
httpPost.addHeader("x-ms-date", dateString);
httpPost.addHeader("x-ms-version", restServiceVersion);
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonValue = gson.toJson(objToDoItem);
System.out.println(jsonValue);

StringEntity requestEntity = new StringEntity(jsonValue);

requestEntity.setContentType("application/json");

httpPost.setEntity(requestEntity);

System.out.println("Before request");  //upto here I can see logs in console
HttpEntity responseEntity = httpClient.execute(httpPost).getEntity();  //no response

System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity));
```

For some reason I can't debug it in Android studio so I have added console logs and I can see logs till- `httpClient.execute` runs. After this line there is no response. I have enclosed it within `try-catch` but there is no exception captured.
Can someone please take a look? Please let me know if I can give some more details.

**Edit**

Here's the complete code for the Async Task-

```
private class CustomAsyncUtil extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String[] params) {
    System.out.println("Inside dobackground");
    //if(android.os.Debug.isDebuggerConnected())
    //    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
    //CreateDocument();
    System.out.println("Inside dobackground after debug point");
    try
    {
        TodoItem objToDoItem = new TodoItem();
        objToDoItem.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        objToDoItem.category = "test android";
        objToDoItem.complete = true;
        objToDoItem.name = "souvik ghosh";

        String HOST = _host;
        String MASTER_KEY = _key;

        String restServiceVersion = "2017-02-22";

        String verb = "post";
        String resourceType = "docs";
        String resourceId = "dbs/ToDoList/colls/Items";
        SimpleDateFormat dateVal = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

        System.out.println("Step 1");

        String dateString = org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils.formatDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

        String gmtIndex = "GMT";
        int index = dateString.indexOf(gmtIndex);

        dateString = dateString.substring(0, index + 3).toLowerCase();

        String payLoad = verb +"\n" + resourceType + "\n" + resourceId + "\n" + dateString + "\n\n";

        System.out.println(payLoad);

        String secretAccessKey = MASTER_KEY;
        String data = payLoad;
        byte[] secretKey = Base64.decode(secretAccessKey, Base64.DEFAULT);
        SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey, "HmacSHA256");
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        mac.init(signingKey);
        byte[] bytes = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(bytes);
        String hashval =  Base64.encodeToString(rawHmac, Base64.DEFAULT);

        org.apache.http.client.HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(HOST);

        httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", hashval );
        httpPost.addHeader("x-ms-date", dateString);
        httpPost.addHeader("x-ms-version", restServiceVersion);
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonValue = gson.toJson(objToDoItem);
        System.out.println(jsonValue);

        StringEntity requestEntity = new StringEntity(jsonValue);

        requestEntity.setContentType("application/json");

        httpPost.setEntity(requestEntity);

        System.out.println("Before request");
        HttpEntity responseEntity = httpClient.execute(httpPost).getEntity();

        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Inside catch block");
        System.out.println("Exception details: " + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Stack trace: " + ex.getStackTrace());
    }
    System.out.println("Step end");
    return "some message";
}
```

This is how I call it in `onCreate` inside my activity class-

```
try
{
    CustomAsyncUtil objUtil = new CustomAsyncUtil();
    objUtil.execute();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    String exp = ex.getMessage();
}
```

Here's the Logcat details-

```
I/System.out: Inside dobackground 
I/System.out: Inside dobackground after debug point 
I/System.out: Step 1 
I/System.out: post 
I/System.out: docs 
I/System.out: dbs/ToDoList/colls/Items 
I/System.out: sat, 09 dec 2017 04:26:58 gmt 
I/System.out: {"category":"test android","complete":true,"id":"0846439f-4951-4475-9ea5-d7937c32d479","name":"souvik ghosh"} 
I/System.out: Before request 
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8621', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that Apache HTTP is deprecated as of Android 23 in favor of HTTPUrlConnection, but you can use Volley, as the Android documentation describes

Comment: As a suggestion get updated, use [RetroFit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for networking . Its pretty fast and easy to integrate.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah I saw. But anyways this should work I suppose?

Comment: Should, but can you show a [mcve] of your AsyncTask?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, I will update the question with more details.

Comment: Also, how are you comparing "no response" to an empty string, or an exception?

Comment: @cricket_007 Please check the updated post

Comment: And the logcat, please? Does it just pause and wait? How large is the expected response? Is the server even getting the message?

Comment: @cricket_007 Added the  logcat details. The response is like 3 lines of raw JSON in case of error and 20 to 30 lines in case of success.

Comment: I'd say use some other REST client to hit your server with the same payload and see if it times out.

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried the same with C# `HttpClient` and Restman in Opera. Both works, also the hash value of the auth token is same. Just wondering if the headers and all are constructed well here. May be I will try with a different approach instead of the deprecated version of `HttpClient`

Comment: Okay, I mean, as far as I can tell, it's doing what it is supposed to. Just the server isn't responding

Comment: @cricket_007 I will post the details here in case I find some solution to this. Thanks

Comment: Internet Permissions in MANIFEST granted?

Comment: @Aqua4 Yes, or I would have got permission error

Comment: `Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8621',`. Localhost? Please show your url. Who is pinting that log? And where?